# Android Studio: Does clean build rebuilds all modules or just the selected module?

Tags: android

In my android project, there are two android apps configured as modules. I choose the app to run by selecting it in run configurations.

My question is, if I do a rebuild from build menu, does it rebuild both my modules or just the module which is currently selected in the run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all possible configurations, so the best way to know for sure is experimental verification; if you open the 'Gradle Console' window in Android Studio (making an assumption about IDE) it should show you exactly what tasks run when you clean or rebuild. For my project (a application module and two library modules) only the application module gets cleaned by default, but all modules are getting recompiled.